# What center point does DW use on my inline list?

Tags: html, css

So I've center aligned the text "Jonathon Smith Photography".  Directly below it in a different DIV, I've center aligned an inline list (my navbar) containing "Portfolio Contact Bio".  However they appear to be centered at different points?  The "Jon smith photography" text has no other properties to it.  The list items in the navbar (not the navbar div itself) have a background color as well as padding above/below/left/right of it.  However, when I disable the color/padding properties, the texts still appear to be centered at different points.  Now I'm guessing the list's centerpoint that is off since it's a little more complex than the plain text.  How do I get them to align properly?

HTML:

```
<div id="title">Johnathon Smith Photography</div>

<div id="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li>Portfolio</li>
    <li>Contact</li>
    <li>Bio</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#title {
text-align: center;
}
#navbar ul li {
background-color: #00225A;
display: inline;
list-style-type: none;
color: #fff;
padding-top: 0.2em;
padding-right: 1em;
padding-bottom: 0.2em;
padding-left: 1em;
}
#navbar {
text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this:

```
#navbar ul {
       padding-left: 0;   
}
```

The ul has a padding in the left by default.

Comment: brilliant! So when adding properties through my source code, where must I place the cursor to add the property to the div and the ul, but not the li?  because when i put the cursor after the opening ul tag but before the li tags, DW still only adds the property to the div instead of both the div and the ul.  hope that makes sense

Comment: If you want to add properties to the div, it will be #navbar. Properties to the UL it is #navbar ul and to the li then you use #navbar ul li. If you want to add the same properties to the div and the ul, you can use #navbar, #navbar ul { ...properties... }